# Getting Error 403 when pushing using Git command line

Tags: git, github, repo

I am trying to push code to my own repo where I am the sole user, administrator and owner.

I have updated my `.github/config` many times (I am using HTTPS for a specific reason).

I have checked my profile to ensure I am all verified (don't understand why I wouldn't be, been a member for years now).

No matter what I setup I just keep getting

```
remote: Permission to <user>/<repo>.git denied to <user>.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I have scoured stack-overflow and the internet to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you checked if there's any issue with the SSH key? Try adding your SSH key in github again.

Comment: Yep, rebuilt the Fine Grained Token as well...

Comment: Umm.. try once `classic token` instead of `fine grained`

Comment: Same, the `git push` doesn't even ask for a password...

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have fixed it, not sure if this is THE solution, but this worked for me ;)

in the `.github/config` file I didn't have a `[User]` section and I didn't have a user in my github URL...

```
...
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://<user>:<token>@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
...
[user]
    name = <My Name>
    email = <My Email Address>
[credential]
    username = <My Email Address>
...
```

Once I corrected this, it started letting me push again...

And after the initial push I can remove the `<user>:<token>` bit from the `url`.

I also created a Token (Classic) instead of Fine Grained, but I will look into migrating this over to Fine Grained eventually, I just need to get my work out there :/

UPDATE: Managed to get this over to a Fine Grained token...